# Python - re.match: how do i get my code to print out the phone line in the my data file when my input is i have a phone

Tags: python, python-3.x

> In my file i have a python code and a text file, however in the text file i have a the words phone and iphone, but when the user input is *i have a phone* it matches the input with iphone instead of phone. How Do i Solve This Problem? code below:

```
import re
import string

device = input("What device do you have? ")

device_Array= device.split()


for key_word in device_Array:
    for line in open("Data_file.txt"):
        if key_word in line :
            if re.match(key_word,line):
                phone=input(line[9:])
```

Snippet of txt file

```
Phone  - What type of phone do you have?
phone  - What type of phone do you have?
Apple  - what type of iphone do you have?
apple  - what type of iphone do you have?
Iphone - what model of iphone do you have?
iphone - what model of iphone do you have?
```

Comment: Use `if key_word in line.split()` instead.

Comment: Please also add an example of text file contents.

Comment: The problem is that the `i` of `i have ...` matches the `i` of `iphone`. What is your goal?

Comment: I am trying to get to get the use input to match a word in the txt file, so that it can print a out a relevant question for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in values that you provide as arguments to [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match):

Given the keywords in user input "i have a phone", `re.match` will return True because some of the keywords (in this case "i", "phone") are present in the variable `line` (in this case a line containing "iphone").

- Update: @Jasper is right - "i" would also match "iphone". Edited the answer accordingly (initially I noticed only that "phone" would be a match).

P.S. It would help if you provided a snippet of the text file that the code works with. that would make it more clear what is happening.

Comment: I have added a snippet of the txt file to the question